# Binding Toggle Buttons to each other using Glade & GTK+ (in C)

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I have two toggle buttons named RUN and KILL. When I toggle on (i.e. depress) the RUN button, I only want it to toggle off by depressing the KILL toggle button (NOT by toggling off the RUN button). I want any subsequent mouse clicks on the RUN button to do nothing unless the KILL button is depressed. Likewise, when the KILL button is toggled on, I only want it to toggle off by depressing the RUN button (again, NOT by toggling off the KILL button). I am not sure how to construct the event handlers that would bind the action of these two toggle buttons together. I am using GTK+ together with Glade and programming in C.

Comment: This would be highly unpractical, as the relationship between the buttons would not necessarily be obvious. Don't make widgets act in a different way that what they look. Have you considered just using a single toggle button, changing the name from RUN to KILL when it is pressed? Maybe using a normal button would be enough and not a toggle one in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `GtkToggleButton` is a generic button and it will toggle with all user interactions we must prevent it from toggling under certain conditions. In this case, the button after being toggled can't be toggled again on itself but via another toggle button. To achieve this, you must:

1. Prevent button events from toggling the button under certain conditions
2. Bind both buttons with inverted logic (mutually exclusive)

To achieve 1) we can connect a callback to the `GtkWidget` `"button-press-event"` signal and return according to the wanted conditions, with TRUE preventing the signal from propagating and FALSE otherwise.

Then, to handle 2), we can use g_object_bind_property for the `GtkToggleButton "active"` property with `G_BINDING_INVERTED_BOOLEAN` flag to get the desired behavior. Notice that we must set one of them active as a start condition.

So, a simple example could be:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean on_toggle_button_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data) {
   if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget)) == TRUE) {
      return TRUE;
   }

   return FALSE;
}

void on_run_toggle_active(GObject *obj, GParamSpec *pspec, gpointer user_data) {
   g_return_if_fail (user_data != NULL);

   GtkLabel *label = GTK_LABEL(user_data);
   GtkToggleButton *button = GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(obj);

   if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(button) == TRUE) {
      gtk_label_set_text (label, "Running...");
   } else {
      gtk_label_set_text (label, "Idle");
   }
}

gint main(gint argc, gchar **argv) {
   GtkLabel *status;
   GtkWindow *window;
   GtkBuilder *builder;
   GtkToggleButton *run_toggle;
   GtkToggleButton *kill_toggle;

   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("gui.ui");

   window      = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
   status      = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "status"));
   run_toggle  = GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "toggle"));
   kill_toggle = GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "kill"));

   g_object_bind_property (G_OBJECT(run_toggle), "active", G_OBJECT(kill_toggle), "active", G_BINDING_INVERT_BOOLEAN);
   g_object_bind_property (G_OBJECT(kill_toggle), "active", G_OBJECT(run_toggle), "active", G_BINDING_INVERT_BOOLEAN);

   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(run_toggle), "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_toggle_button_press_event), NULL);
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(kill_toggle), "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_toggle_button_press_event), NULL);
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(run_toggle), "notify::active", G_CALLBACK(on_run_toggle_active), status);
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

   gtk_main();

   return 0;
}
```

To simplify, I've outlined the user interface with glade (**gui.ui**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.18"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="halign">center</property>
        <property name="valign">center</property>
        <property name="row_spacing">20</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="status">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Idle</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkToggleButton" id="toggle">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="focus_on_click">False</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkBox">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="spacing">3</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="icon_name">media-playback-start-symbolic</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">0</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Run</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkToggleButton" id="kill">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="active">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkBox">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="spacing">3</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="icon_name">user-trash-symbolic</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">0</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Kill</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <style>
              <class name="linked"/>
            </style>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkSizeGroup">
    <widgets>
      <widget name="label1"/>
      <widget name="label2"/>
    </widgets>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

And the output should be something like this:

[image: output]

The Toggle Buttons are mutually exclusive and pressing them while active won't have any visual effect.

PS: No keyboard handling is assumed, otherwise we must handle those signals and act accordingly.